# Can I use national inflation rate with panel data across the states?

Tags: regression, panel-data

I'm doing a regression with panel data across all 50 states with variables like Per Capita Income, Minimum Wage, Population and Unemployment Rate. I am wondering if since I can't find great data on inflation for each state, can I combine the national inflation rate in the panel data regression?

Comment: While the states do have different per capita incomes, and different unemployment rates, they are using the same currency - so there is some validity to using the national inflation rate for all states. True, things like gasoline or eggs have price differentials across states so this is not perfect but it is not totally invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you are trying to do exactly, but in principal in statistical terms this is fine as long as you have a time dimension over which the national inflation rate varies. Obviously you can't identify the effect of the inflation on each state, but if that is not the goal there shouldn't be any problem.